# How to make Wso2 API Manager Access token expire time to infinte?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using Wso2 API Manager 1.8. I have created some apis in it, and   subscribed it to an application. I Want to make the token expire time to infinte , means never expire token. I have gone through the tutorial given in wso2 site and done following changes.

refered link : [Changing the default token expiration time](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM160/Working+with+Access+Tokens#WorkingwithAccessTokens-changeDef)

I have changed `ApplicationAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod` to -1 . Rest remains same. And I created new application to get the changes, Now get long integer value `9223372036854452224` ie `106751991` days) as expire time. And working fine .

Then I changed the system date to next day check whether the expire not set to zero. But my token expire time chages to 3600000 milliseconds, How this happens, even if the time reduces this much change never expecting.

I have chages the default H2 database to mysql and done same thing with this.

Then I noticed that when the day changes,the token expire time reduces from `9223372036854452224`  to `3600000` milliseconds means 1hr of expire time, which is default time. Actually it have `106751991` days expire time.  How this happening ?

Please help. How can I solve this problem

Comment: what is the OS that you are using ?

Comment: Please use correct formatting. you mean after changing ApplicationAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod to -1 still token expire?

Comment: @vanji  - I am using Windows 7

Comment: Changing it to -1 should work

Answer (score 2):

Set token validity time to -1 (minus one) - that means never expires (also, see if that is the value that you have in API Store on Subscriptions tab)

Comment: that i have done already .and its displaying in store also for applications created after these settings . still i have problem